# What is my minhag?

Tags: minhag, nuschaot

My family is from the former soviet Union (Beltsy Moldova, but my great grandparents are from Otaki (Near Ribnitz), Skulen, and Rashkov. I never my parents were divorced, to the point where I do not know my father. My grandfather's minhag was unknown. However, my great grandmother said that she remembered one thing: We sit down during kaddish yatom which is a sefardi custom. I keep switching between minhagim as a result. What nusach should I daven?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. 
You have an interesting question here.
But  Mi Yodeya is not set up to answer it. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for guidance. 
It says particularly:

"Questions that appear to be requests for personal practical advice will be either edited to more general wording or closed."

The best thing to do is to ask the local Rabbi to whom you can relate.

Comment: This is very specifically a question that only a Rabbi who can sit down with you and get to know you can answer. I hope you stick around and ask more questions! Hatzlacha

Comment: There's a strong argument to be made, absent a clear family minhag, to find a community with which you fit and take up their customs.